# TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|filesize equivalent in TYPO3 7.6 or 8.7

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.7.x

Back in TYPO3 4.5 there was `TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|filesize` to access the filesize of the last rendered image in TypoScript. Is there an equivalent in TYPO3 7.6.x or 8.7.x?

I would need it here:

```
70 = CONTENT
70 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    orderBy = sorting
    where = colPos=0
    pidInList.data = field : content_from_pid
    max = 1
  }
  wrap = <enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="{$rssFeed.feedBaseUrl}|" />

  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = FILES
    10 {
      references {
        table = tt_content
        uid.data = uid
        fieldName = image
      }
      renderObj = COA
      renderObj {
        10 = IMG_RESOURCE
        10 {
          file {
            import.data = file:current:originalUid
            width.field = imagewidth
            maxW = {$rssFeed.feedImageMaxWidth}
          }
        }

        20 = TEXT
        # this used to work in TYPO3 4.5
        20.data = TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo|filesize
        20.wrap = " length="|
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `TSFE:lastImageInfo`, even in [TYPO3 4.5](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/class_8tslib__fe_8php_source.html#l00338). Seems to be set in later versions, too.

Answer (score 0):

`TSFE:lastImgResourceInfo` still exists in 7.x and later, but the field `filesize` is gone. I couldn't find any information in the code where it has gone.